# libgcrypt-config --libs: no such file or directory

Tags: c

I'm using gcrypt, but my compiler seems to unable to find it. Here is my makefile. function.c is a function source file containing functions I defined; I also wrote a header file miao.h with function declaration, and gcrypt.h is included in it. main.c is a source file including miao.h. When I do make: [image].Could anyone help me? This bothers me so long.

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = 'libgcrypt-config --cflags'
LIBS = 'libgcrypt-config --libs'
OBJS = function.o main.o main

all: $(OBJS)

function.o: function.c
    $(CC) -c function.c $(CFLAGS)

main.o: main.c
    $(CC) -c main.c  $(CFLAGS)

main: main.o function.o
    $(CC) -o main main.o function.o $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm $(OBJS)
```

Comment: the files all seem to be `C` files, suggest removing the `c++` tag.

Answer (score 0):

the makefile should be written more like the following:

caveat: I was unable to test the makefile as I do not have libgcrypt-config available.

Per the web site: `https://gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt/Building-sources.html` the `libgcrypt-config` is an executable so should be surrounded by back-ticks, not single quotes so it will be executed in the current shell.

(back ticks on stackoverflow will result in emphasised text but should still be visible as to where they should be placed.)

Note: where I have placed `<tab>` your actual makefile needs to have a tab character

Note: targets, like `all` and `clean` do not produce a file with the same name, so early in the file there needs to be the statement: `.PHONY: all clean`

when defining a macro, use `:=` rather than `=` so the macro is only evaluated once.

Any calls to shell functions should be incorporated via a macro, so it is easy to make a change.  In general it is best to include the path to the shell function:   I wrote this on Linux, your path may be different.  Specifying the actual path becomes very important when cross compiling or there are duplicate names visible via the $PATH statement (as can easily be the case with `gcc`)

Note: the actual `libgcrypt-config` executable must be in visible via your $PATH environment variable.

Note: all the individual compile statements could be reduced to the following two lines: (and nothing else needed for the compiles)

```
%.o: %.c 
<tab>$(CC)  -c $< -o $@ -I. $(CFLAGS)
```

Note: do not place the contents of a rule where the `dependencies` is expected.   This error was noted in the `clean:` target

the proposed makefile follows:

```
CC := /usr/bin/gcc
RM := /usr/bin/rm

CFLAGS := `libgcrypt-config --cflags`

LIBS := `libgcrypt-config --libs`

OBJS := function.o main.o main

TARGET := main

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(TARGET)

function.o: function.c
<tab>$(CC) -c function.c $(CFLAGS) -o function.o -I.

main.o: main.c
<tab>$(CC) -c main.c  $(CFLAGS) -o main.o -I.

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
<tab>$(CC) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

clean:
<tab>$(RM) -f $(OBJS)
```